# return qs._result_cache[0] IndexError: list index out of range [12/Jul/2022 14:43:28] "GET /shop/products/15 HTTP/1.1" 500 68001

Tags: python, django

return qs._result_cache[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
[12/Jul/2022 14:43:28] "GET /shop/products/15 HTTP/1.1" 500 68001

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`qs._result_cache` obviously is an empty list or string.